# What is the penalty for fighting while blind?

Tags: combat, conditions, pathfinder-2e, blind

What happens when an enemy is blinded and wants to fight? What penalty does the enemy get when he wants to attack?

Is the enemy flat footed?

Answer (score 12):

### Let's take a look at what the Blinded condition does.

[**Blinded**](https://2e.aonprd.com/Conditions.aspx?ID=1)  <sub>*(Core Rulebook pg. 618)*</sub>

> You can’t see. All normal terrain is difficult terrain to you. You can’t detect anything using vision. You automatically critically fail Perception checks that require you to be able to see, and if vision is your only precise sense, you take a –4 status penalty to Perception checks. You are immune to visual effects. Blinded overrides Dazzled.

Let's tackle it does step by step.

> You can’t see. All normal terrain is difficult terrain to you.

That means you can't step, and that you stride at half speed.

> You can’t detect anything using vision.

That means that everything is either Hidden or Undetected to you, unless you have a method of detecting them other than vision, such as blindsight. And *that* means you need to pass a DC 11 flat check to attack anything, and that's assuming you know what square your target is in. You are also flat-footed, because you are flat-footed against enemies that are Hidden or Undetected.

> You automatically critically fail Perception checks that require you to be able to see, and if vision is your only precise sense, you take a –4 status penalty to Perception checks.

This essentially means that you have a -4 penalty to figure out which square something is in, so that you can make your DC 11 check to possibly attack it.

Comment: Concise, nice answer

Comment: As currently written it's not clear why "You can’t detect anything using vision" causes that DC11 stuff. Presumably it's referencing a different set of rules, which you should also quote for clarity.

Comment: @Ruse It's part of the rules for Hidden, and quoting the rules for every condition that Blinded imposes would result in a significant amount of bloat on this answer.